# Tableau - Filter based on parameter

Tags: date, filter, parameters, tableau-api

I have a dataset of dates. It has just one column **CreatedOnDate** and its values are in datetime as shown below.

[image]

This dataset has 6 months of values as shown. I have a parameter called **Report Type** which has possible values Monthly, Weekly, Daily (Screenshot below)

[image]

I have created a calculated field (called **Created On Date**) which converts the date based on Report Type selected. The formula is shown below

```
CASE [Report Type]
    WHEN "Monthly" THEN DATENAME('month', [CreatedOnDate])
    WHEN "Weekly" THEN "Week " + STR(DATEPART('week',[CreatedOnDate]))
    WHEN "Daily" THEN STR(MONTH([CreatedOnDate])) + "/" + STR(DAY([CreatedOnDate])) + "/" + STR(YEAR([CreatedOnDate]))
END
```

This works perfectly. The result of the calculated field is shown below.

[image]

I now need to incorporate the following logic

```
IFF Report Type = "Daily" Display only the last 30 days in the dataset
Other cases Show all values
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**woodhead92**, I'd suggest using so called [Level of Detail expressions](http://www.tableau.com/about/blog/LOD-expressions) that were introduced in Tableau v8. First create a calculated field that will calculate the most recent (=MAX) date available:

```
{FIXED : MAX(CreatedOnDate) }
```

Let's call this *MaxDate LOD*. Then adding a new calculated field *Show/Hide*:

```
IF [Report Type] = "Daily" AND 
  ([CreatedOnDate] >= DATEADD('day', -30, [MaxDate LOD]) THEN 'Show'
ELSEIF [Report Type] = "Weekly" OR [Report Type] = "Monthly" THEN 'Show'
ELSE 'Hide'
END
```

Add this filter and select 'Show' value only. I am assuming that you want to see all dates when Weekly/Monthly date granularity is selected - if that's not the case, simply add more *ELSEIF* conditions.

The formula above could be simplified, but I wanted to make it as verbose as possible so that it helps you understand how Level of Detail expressions work.

One thing to keep in mind - *FIXED* LOD calculation overwrites filters, so if you have a date-range filter available, you will have to make sure it's *added to context*. More details on filter context are available here in [this a bit out-dated, but still excellent blog post](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tableau/tableau_context_filters.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Create a calculated field for your condition and then place it on the filter shelf to include only rows that evaluate to true.

```
[Report Date] <> "Daily" or 
datediff('day', [CreatedOnDate], { max[CreatedOnDate] } < 30
```

The Curley braces are significant, an LOD calculation